# Expected An Expression / Type Name Not Allowed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

```
Brixpath::Brixpath(){
{    _animationOptions = (AnimationOptions){5, 3, 40, 30}; 
};
```

When I run this code block VS gives error

> typename not allowed on AnimationOptions.

When I remove the typename

```
Brixpath::Brixpath(){
{    _animationOptions = {5, 3, 40, 30}; 
};
```

VS2010 gives the error at the 1st "{" in 2nd line

> Error: Expected an expression

The definition of Animation Options is-

```
struct AnimationOptions {
int maxClicks; //how many clicks animation on screen to support
int step; // animation speed, 3 pixels per time
int limit; //width of animation rectangle. if more, rectangle dissapears
int distance; //minimum distance between previous click and current
};
```

How do I solve this error? Please help.

Comment: Just a guess, but does `_animationOptions = AnimationOptions{5, 3, 40, 30};` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the user of VS 2010 (i.e., you can't use C++11 uniform initialization), you probably want to add a constructor to your struct, then use it to initialize your structure:

```
struct AnimationOptions {
    int maxClicks; //how many clicks animation on screen to support
    int step; // animation speed, 3 pixels per time
    int limit; //width of animation rectangle. if more, rectangle dissapears
    int distance; //minimum distance between previous click and current

    AnimationOptions(int maxClicks, int step, int limit, int distance) : 
        maxClicks(maxClicks), step(step), limit(limit), distance(distance) {}
};

Brixpath::Brixpath() : _animationOptions(5, 3, 40, 30) {}
```

If you need to maintain AnimationOptions as a POD, I believe you can simplify the code a bit with braced initialization rather than member-wise initialization:

```
AnimationOptions make_ao(int clicks, int step, int limit, int distance)
{
  AnimationOptions ao = {clicks, step, limit, distance};
  return ao;
};
```

Comment: `make_ao`, I like that :)

Answer (score 2):

This would work and would be the preferred option (C++11 required):

```
Brixpath::Brixpath() : _animationOptions{5, 3, 40, 30}
{
};
```

Here, you *initialize* `_animationOptions` in the constructor initialization list instead of *assigning* a value to it in the constructor's body.

In the absence of C++11 support, you can either give `AnimationOptions` a constructor, in which case it will not be a POD anymore, or set element by element. If this is an issue, you can also make an initializer function:

```
AnimationOptions make_ao(int clicks, int step, int limit, int distance)
{
  AnimationOptions ao;
  ao.maxClicks = clicks;
  ao.step = step;
  ....
  return ao;
};
```

Then

```
Brixpath::Brixpath() : _animationOptions(make_ao(5, 3, 40, 30))
{
};
```

This keeps `AnimationOptions` as POD, and de-couples initialization from the constructor code.

Comment: Note that the assignment syntax used in the OP's sample, will also compile only when C++11 standard is used.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I solve this error?

Either use the c++11 standard option to compile your code, or initialize the struct memberwise:

```
Brixpath::Brixpath()
{    
    _animationOptions.maxClicks = 5;
    _animationOptions.step = 3;
    _animationOptions.limit = 40
    _animationOptions.distance = 30; 
};
```